# API calls #LinkedIn for r_basicprofile

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have read carefully the LinkedIn developer documents regarding API calls, following the documents, I was able to request the access code, exchange it with server and manage to get access token.

After that I managed to get some of the member's profile, using the access token in json format with the below code.

```
$api_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address)?format=json';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken
    ),
));

$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

however the issue is: trying to conduct any different calls will fail, although they are as per the documents of LinkedIn and they are allowed for the r_basicprofile, but yet the error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/~:(industryId~)?format=json):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

I tried some of the following but nothing goes right

```
$api_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken
    ),
));

$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

I even tried to get memeber's profile with the below GET requests, but same 403 returned.

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID})
>
> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{profileID})?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,industryId~)

Would appreciate to understand how to make those calls, and what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the V2 api requires you to get a partnership with linkedin. this means you get the 403 forbidden error.

> Partnering with LinkedIn provides you with additional API
>   functionality & data access, increased call limits & dedicated
>   support. Read more about our various Partner Programs and use cases
>   and see if one is a match for your app. Applications are only accepted
>   when we feel that they're providing value to members, developers and
>   LinkedIn.

**source:**  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

fortunatly for you there is a V1 version of the api you require.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{ID}?format=json
```

Comment: Many thanks for the info, could you please give me a link to some material to read about the V1, as except for the basic API call, all other calls as per LinkedIn documents are for V2, moreover the variables in GET request are different between versions (i.e. v1: first-name, v2: firstname), therefore I should have some better reading

Comment: unfortunantly there is no/lack of information about the linkedin api V1.

but for the people api all possibilities i found are:

`/v1/people/[personID]:(firstName,lastName,headline,positions:(company,title,summary,startDate,endDate,isCurrent),industry,location:(name,country:(code)),pictureUrl,publicProfileUrl,emailAddress)?format=json`

Answer (score 0):

Add your LinkedIN JS SDK to your site, should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key:                 <!-- YOUR CLIENT ID (API KEY) HERE -->
  onLoad:                  LinkedINJSAPI.onLoad
  authorize:               true
  credentials_cookie:      true
  credentials_cookie_crc:  true
</script>
```

After which in your JavaScript add in the following:

```
 var LinkedINJSAPI = {
   onLoad: function(){
     IN.User.authorize(LinkedINJSAPI.request, this );
   },
   request: function(){
    var url = 'people/~:(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,positions,location)?format=json';
    IN.API.Raw(url).
      method('GET').
      result(function(result){
        console.log( JSON.stringify( result ) );
      }).
      error(function(error){
        console.error( error.message );
      });
   }
 }
```

You can see a working demo here...

https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/KGbqRq