# I need vanityName from the r_liteprofile

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I need vanityName  from r_liteprofile, I have do R&D on developer.linkedin.com but didn't get any reference from developer account, so any suggestion or any link Where I can find out the solution of the getting vanityName from r_liteprofile from Linkdin because they deprecated V1 forms so in V2 API they allow only liteprofile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: They no longer expose this. Once upon a time you could sign up for their “partner program” for `r_basicprofile` access, but that program [appears to have been suspended](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/topics/6400/6401/97491/partner-programs?lang=en). So, I do not believe it is possible to retrieve this anymore.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56255927/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936376/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=r_basicprofile+LinkedIn or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context.

Comment: Any option to show user profile like using www.linkedin.com/in/{vanityName}

Comment: Nope. This is why we all want the vanity name and they just don’t expose it. It’s annoying.